# Custom structure using jSONEncoder

Tags: swift, serialization, encodable, jsonencoder

Want to encode an object into a custom structure using JSONEncoder+Encodable.

```
struct Foo: Encodable {
   var name: String?
   var bars: [Bar]?
}

struct Bar: Encodable {
   var name: String?
   var value: String?
}

let bar1 = Bar(name: "bar1", value: "barvalue1")
let bar2 = Bar(name: "bar2", value: "barvalue2")
let foo = Foo(name: "foovalue", bars: [bar1, bar2])
```

Default approach of encoding `foo` gives:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let data = try encoder.encode(foo)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Output:

```
{
   "name": "foovalue",
   "bars": [
      {
         "name": "bar1",
         "value": "barvalue1"
      },
      {
         "name": "bar2",
         "value": "barvalue2"
      }
   ]
}
```

In the custom output I'd like to use the value of property `name` as the key, and the values of rest as the value for the mentioned key. The same will be applicable for nested objects. So I'd expect the output to be:

```
{
    "foovalue": [
       {
          "bar1": "barvalue1"
       },
       {
          "bar2": "barvalue2"
       }
     ]
}
```

Question is whether Encodable/JSONEncoder supports this. Right now I just process the the first output dictionary and restructure it by iterating the keys.

Comment: This is possible by [overriding `Bar`'s `func encode(to:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) and creating your own `CodingKey`s. However, this format can be somewhat ambiguous — why are you looking to do it this way? What if you need to add further properties in the future?

Comment: you mean `Foo(name: "foo", bars: [bar1, bar2])`

Comment: @ItaiFerber That's just the requirement for now :). I was thinking CodingKeys only allows renaming or omitting properties, I'll explore more.

Comment: @LeoDabus Just edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @justintime If you write your own `encode(to:)` you can define `CodingKey`s however you need to and use them however you like — in this case you can define a struct which conforms to `CodingKey` and can take on any `String` value

Comment: @ItaiFerber I think you've pointed me to the right direction, I'll try out dynamic coding keys and my own implementation of `encoder(to:)`.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's sort of what I'm doing right now, but'd want to see what Encodable is capable of out of the box. :)

Comment: @LeoDabus For one thing, Codable can support more than one encoding format should you want it. In this small example, yes, the benefit might be marginal, but scaled up, its likely worth it.

Comment: @LeoDabus As mentioned above — create a struct which conforms to `CodingKey` that you can assign any string value to. Assign a key the value of `name` and use that key to encode `value` in your overridden `encode(to:)`. I’m not at a computer ATM but I can give an example once I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’d like to keep `Foo` and `Bar` `Encodable`, you can achieve this by providing a custom `encode(to:)` that uses a specific coding key whose value is `name`:

```
private struct StringKey: CodingKey {
    let stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init(_ string: String) { stringValue = string }
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue) }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}

struct Foo: Encodable {
    var name: String
    var bars: [Bar]

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: StringKey.self)
        try container.encode(bars, forKey: StringKey(name))
    }
}

struct Bar : Encodable {
    var name: String
    var value: String

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: StringKey.self)
        try container.encode(value, forKey: StringKey(name))
    }
}
```

`StringKey` can take on any `String` value, allowing you to encode arbitrarily as needed.

Comment: @LeoDabus Correct — you can apply the same treatment to Foo as well for the same effect. Will expand to include that.

Comment: Yup that's what I came up with, does the trick nicely! Cuts down a lot of extra code. Thanks!